# Append timestamp in gifs using js to prevent caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, gif

Hello I am using Revolution Slider ([sample here](http://revolution.themepunch.com/wordpress-slideshow-gallery/)) with a GIF in it. I have four slides and all of them uses the same image source for the GIF.

Problem is that it's loading the GIF only once on the first slide then from the second slide onwards, it's not animating anymore - which I assume is because of cache. I would like to try the solutions I found online about appending timestamp or random query like this `<img src="image.gif?01234">`

But since it's loaded from a slider, all I can do is assign an ID or class for each of them then append the timestamp using JS. And I'm not really familiar with JS. Help, anyone?

Comment: Can you provide link of plugin you are using? its hard to guess how RevSlider loads the slider

Comment: You shouldn't need to reset the src with a timestamped version, which will make the browser to reask the server to get the file. Normally, just setting `img.src = img.src;` should restart a non-looping gif. Also, you could try to modify your gifs so they do loop :-)

Comment: @RaunakKathuria sorry about that please see my edits

@Kaiido how do you suggest I set thr `img.src = img.src`? I have really low knowledge of js. By the way the gif does loop, but only once. When it's displayed again on other sliders, it's just the first frame that's appearing but everytime I reload the page it animates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you described that if you have id or class you can modify source using javascript like this

**HTML**

```
<img src="../abc.gif" alt="dummy title" id="img1" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function editSrc() {
  // get current src of image
  var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
  var prevSrc = img1.src;
  alert(prevSrc);
  // get current date
  var dt = new Date();
  // modify img with current timestamp
  img1.src = prevSrc + "?" + dt.getTime();
  alert(img1.src);
}
```

if you want to update it all the time then better to use

```
// split src based on `?` and then take the src before `?`
img1.src = prevSrc.split('?')[0] + "?" + dt.getTime();
```

instead of

```
img1.src = prevSrc + "?" + dt.getTime();
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dw47cw5p/2/)**